# R.G Bartle 4th edition problem no. 14 of 1st chapter 1st section

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Show that if $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $E$ and $F$ are subsets of $A$, then
$$f(E\cap F)\subseteq f(E)\cap f(F)$$

I tried to prove it like this 
Consider any element $y \in f(E\cap F)$, then there must be an pre-image of $y$ in $E\cap F$, say $x$, such that $y=f(x)$, i.e $x\in E\cap F \Rightarrow x\in E \,\, \wedge\,\, x\in F\\\Rightarrow f(x)\in f(E) \, \wedge \, f(x) \in f(F)\\\Rightarrow f(x)\in f(E)\cap f(F)$

Since $y$ is the image of $x$ under $f$, i.e $y=f(x)$, we conclude $y\in f(E)\cap f(F)$

Thus $$f(E\cap F)\subseteq f(E)\cap f(F)$$

• Is the above proof is done right ?

• Can I extend it to show $$f(E\cap F)= f(E)\cap f(F)$$
Since I didn't get any kind of contradiction to show
$$f(E)\cap f(F)\nsubseteq f(E\cap F)  $$

Comment: Is the above approach correct, I mean does it lacks some important step or argument.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But for the rest of your question, you haven't even done any exploration of the other direction. Your comment about that is a little like doubting the existence of the Eiffel tower, since you didn't see it at all during an extensive visit to London. I suggest you play around with sets $E, F$ of just a few elements each, and try to construct a counter-example. If you can, you have your answer. If you cannot, you have some valuable experience towards constructing a proof of the other direction.

Comment: And for ideas about how to construct a counter-example, I suggest you try to recall William Elliot's unjustly deleted post (still visible to those of us with sufficient reputation). He was offering an *example*, not a universal statement. Thus he can add any requirements to $f$ and the sets that do not contradict the hypotheses, as long as there are functions/sets that meet those conditions.

Comment: Does $f$ being a periodic functions works as the counter example ?

Comment: Like say $E:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : p < x < q\}$ and $F := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : p+T < x < q+ T\}$ where $T$ is the period of $f$. Then $E$ and $F$ are disjoint sets, so $E\cap F = \emptyset$. But $f(E) = f(F)$. So $f(E) \cap f(F) \neq \emptyset$ but $f(E\cap F) = f(\emptyset) =\emptyset$. Hence $f(E) \cap f(F) \nsubseteq f(E\cap F)$

Comment: Yes that gives a counter-example. A simpler one is $A = \{0, 1\}, E = \{0\}, F = \{1\}$ and $\forall x, f(x) = 2$. When I said play with $E$ and $F$ having only a few elements each, I meant it. When examining basic set operations, seeing how things work for small sets is generally a very useful thing to examine.